# Does the notion of layout exist in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I am a beginner in Vue.js, and do not know if what I want to do is possible or not.

I have several components which must be included in the same 'layout1', and other components which must be included in another same 'layout2'.

The components look like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    bla bla ...
  </div>
</template>
```

So in this component, I find to do something like that:

```
<template>
    
    <this component extends a layout...>
  <div>
    bla bla ...
  </div>
</template>
```

And in the layout, something like that:

```
<template>
   <my components will be rendered here...>
</template>
```

For those who know Laravel Blade, it is something very common (extending a layout).

Is this kind of thing possible in Vue.js?

Comment: you can use vue just like you would HTML elements - `<Layout1> ...content... </Layout1>`

Comment: Thanks Derek. I edited the question to be clearer. How to declare in the layout "my component will be rendered here..." ?

Comment: Hi Dom. Another reminder - please refrain from signing your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It exists in [Vue 2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends) and [Vue3](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#extends)!. Here is an [example](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2020/02/24/extending-vuejs-components-templates/)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.